# Comunicação/Autenticação .net para PHP

Tags: php, .net

Preciso de implementar um sistema de autenticação numa página.

O cenário é o seguinte, tenho uma página que só pode ser acedida por utilizadores autenticados que vêm  de um site (em ASP). Isto do lado do cliente.

Pensei num cenário em que do meu lado existisse um mecanismo (em PHP) que validasse se o cliente estava/vinha autenticado ou não... Pensei em enviar uma chave encriptada do lado do cliente e que o PHP ao validar essa chave permitisse o acesso aos conteúdos, contudo não sei como o fazer em .net, uma vez que o que o cliente tem é um CMS.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Na aplicação em .Net, crie um botão, por exemplo, onde o usuário clicará para aceder a aplicação em PHP no outro servidor.

Ao clicar nesse botão, é gerado um token (chave criptografada única).

O token servirá como autenticação. A lógica é gerar o toke pelo app .Net e salvá-lo num banco de dados.

Esse token deve estar relacionado com a identificação do usuário na aplicação em PHP. Portanto precisa resolver um meio de criar essa relação.

Um modo simples é uma tela no .Net com um formulário onde o usuário insere os dados de login e senha para acesso a aplicação PHP. Esses dados ficariam salvos no banco de dados do app .Net para então poder relacionar com os tokens.

Uma feita a estrutura, continuamos. Ao clicar no botão, é gerado o token e o usuário é direcionado para o app PHP.

O app PHP recebe o token e verifica se é válido, consultando o banco de dados de onde foi salvo previamente. Para essa consulta, recomenda-se uma API (webservice). Evite fazer uma consulta diretamente ao banco de dados. Consulte por uma API.

Após verificar se o token é válido, caso seja válido, buscará a relação com o usuário e fará a então a autenticação no app PHP.

Importante: O token deve ser excluído ou invalidado sempre que for utilizado. O token só pode ser usado uma vez.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que isso tudo é independente das linguagens que utiliza de ambos os lados. O app .net poderia ser um app JAVA e o app PHP poderia ser um app RoR. A lógica do token de autenticação é a mesma.