# Como passo parâmetros pelo curl?

Tags: php

Colegas,

estou reformulando minha pergunta. Tenho um cliente do qual preciso fazer uma integração de um outro site pelo dele. Estou usando o curl para isso. Porém ao invés do usuário usar o acesso do outro site, a integração faria com que o usuário ao se logar no nosso site, teria o acesso ao conteúdo do site dele, sem precisar se logar de novo. Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
 // Inicia o cURL
$ch = curl_init();
// Define a URL original (do formulário de login)
$campos = array("login"=>$jmUsuario->email,"classroom_id"=>$jmUsuario->email,"sign"=>$sign);
$parametros = json_encode($campos);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.siteX.com.br/api/auth/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
//$response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $content;
```

Comment: "If you are the application owner, check your logs for details." => "Se você é o proprietário da aplicação, verifique seus _logs_ para detalhes"

Comment: Lá Bacco. O erro eu entendi, mas preciso saber como faço para corrigir esse erro.

Comment: Isso não é o erro, isso é um aviso de onde você tem que olhar pra saber o erro que está impedindo a página de ser exibida. E é justamente olhando nos _logs_ que você vai encontrar a razão exata do problema. Sempre que você estiver trabalhando com output de erros desligado, é fundamental ver os _logs_ (na verdade, é importante ver os _logs_ mesmo com exibição de erros ligada).

Comment: Entendi...corrigi e apareceu agora You are being redirected. Outra coisa, quando escrevi "Lá" no meu comentário, era para ser "Olá" rs rs rs.

Comment: Descobriu o problema? Se for o caso, pode postar como resposta (se achar que é algo que pode acontecer com outros usuários). Se for só algum problema de sintaxe, ou muito específico, talvez seja melhor só remover a dúvida. Veja que caso se aplica mais ao seu problema. Responder a própria pergunta é valido dentro das regras do site, e até incentivado quando a pessoa resolve por conta própria.

Comment: Achei nada... estou levando uma surra com isso..rs rs rs.. Em relação ao tempo, coloquei curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0); e está direcionando corretamente, porém está dando erro 404, só que os parâmetros estão corretos. Vou refazer meu código atual no post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Passo 1

Nesse trecho

```
$campos = array("login"=>$jmUsuario->email,"classroom_id"=>$jmUsuario->email,"sign"=>$sign);
$parametros = json_encode($campos);
```

Remova essa linha

```
$parametros = json_encode($campos);
```

## Passo 2

Na linha
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros);`

Troque por
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $campos);`

## Explicação:

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS espera um array ou uma string em formato url encoded.

## Obs:

Isso pode não ser a solução do problema pois não está claro na pergunta onde está o problema.
Apesar disso, é uma sugestão para corrigir um erro visível.

Um outro problema no código que postou está nesse trecho

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
```

Presumo que os dados devem ser enviados pelo método *POST* devido ao parâmetro `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, portanto, sugiro que modifique para

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Caso necessite seguir um redirecionamento, defina os seguintes parâmetros:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); // tempo em segundos
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // em segundos
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // true: permite redirecionamento
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1); // quantidade limite de redirecionamentos permitidos
```

Para mais opções, consulte a lista de parâmetros na documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Onde colocou $campo acho que queria colocar $campos.

Comment: Olá Daniel. Fiz conforme você informou, porém agora aparece "You are being redirected.", mas não redireciona.

Comment: Nesse caso deve definir outros parâmetros. CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT e  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT

Comment: editei com exemplos..

Comment: Perfeito Daniel. Funcionou, porém só mais uma dúvida. Esses comandos tem o mesmo efeito de um formulário POST, pois a proposta do cliente é que faça uma integração no sistema, onde o usuário ao acessar o sistema do cliente, consiga visualizar o site integrado externo sem a necessidade de se logar novamente. Os parâmetros que passei são os mesmos como se fossem de um formulário.  Os códigos teriam a mesma funcionalidade como se o usuário tivesse feito pelo formulário?

Comment: Exato. É como um `<form action.... method=post>  <input type=submit>... `. Mais um conselho, como vc está lidando com autenticação, envolve senha de um usuário. Pense numa forma de trabalhar com tokens de autenticação para garantir maior segurança e privacidade aos seus usuários. Pense numa forma onde nem mesmo você que é o programador do site, não pode saber a senha dos usuários. Exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123543/4793

Comment: Obrigado Daniel pela ajuda e esclarecimentos.