# CURL retorna código 303

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$fields = array('usuario'=>urlencode($jm->Login),'senha'=>$jm->Senha);//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
$fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$url = "https://www.sitecliente.com.br/validar/";
$ch = curl_init();//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);//execute post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);//close connection
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "STATUS: ";
print_r($status);
curl_close($ch);
```

O objetivo é ao clicar em um link dentro do nosso sistema, ser direcionado para um sistema externo. Quando fazemos isso, ele valida, porém a página fica em branco. Ao dar um print no status, retorna a mensagem: STATUS: 303.

Verifiquei que esse erro pode ser porque estamos usando o POST e devemos usar o GET. Como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar pelo método GET:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
```

Alternativamente pode usar `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
```

Lembro de ter respondido algo sobre CURL há alguns meses, então fiz uma busca e para minha surpresa encontrei uma pergunta sua que eu respondi:
[Como passo parâmetros pelo curl?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123866/como-passo-par%C3%A2metros-pelo-curl)

Esse link elucida as mesmas dúvidas que está postando aqui novamente, por isso achei relevante postar.

Voltando ao assunto da pergunta atual, note que isso aqui não faz sentido:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
```

O valor é booleano true/false ou 1/0 onde 1 é true e 0 é false.
Enfim, isso também está explicado no link da pergunta feita em Abril.

Mais uma observação, não estou garantindo que o status http 303 se resolverá pois o problema pode ter causa diferente do que foi comentado na pergunta.

Comment: Olá Daniel. Alterei o código, porém o problema continua.

Comment: @Fox.11, não posso fazer nada com informações vagas.

Comment: Olá Daniel, as informações que posso passar são essas. Gostaria de acessar um sistema externo via post, porém ele valida corretamente, mas não direciona e quando dou um print no status, retorna o 303. Não sei se é a forma como estou programando a curl, por isso gostaria de ajuda...

Comment: Sim, isso está bem claro. Mas não posso fazer nada. Não sei como está fazendo, como é o código da página que recebe os dados, como tentou fazer as alterações , quais as condições dos ambientes, etc.. Enfim, são esses detalhes. Eu posso tentar "chutar" dezenas de opções para resolver mas isso é improdutivo e fora do foco, tornando essa pergunta num serviço de suporte técnico.