# Curl retornando erro: Curl failed: SSL connect error

Tags: php, libcurl, ssl

Minha requisicao é a seguinte:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); //Wait indefinitately 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_exec($ch) === FALSE) {
    die("Curl failed: " . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Porem não uso ssl no meu site. Na pagina em questao não preciso. Mas mesmo assim retorna o erro.

PS: Estava funcionando normalmente, porem hoje apresentou esse erro.

Comment: olha aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123866/como-passo-par%C3%A2metros-pelo-curl

Comment: Obrigado, vou olhar.