# Como passar um parâmetro via curl_exec para outra url com PHP?

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho um PHP que depois de realizar uma operação ele chama uma URL externa e retorna o valor desta URL externa, utilizando curl_exec.

Porém, preciso passar um parâmetro para esta nova url, de preferência como de sessão. Como posso passar este parâmetro que no caso é:

```
$transactionReference
```

Segue meu código:

```
 echo 'codigo da transação: '.$transactionReference;      


        // chama a url de geração da nota fiscal

        // create a new cURL resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set URL and other appropriate options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nhaac.com/envianfe.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $transactionReference); 

        // grab URL and pass it to the browser
        curl_exec($ch);

        // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);
```

Apenas para ilustrar o outro PHP que esta chamada faz está assim:

```
<?php


 session_start();
    require 'conexao.php';

    if($transactionReference):
         echo 'codigo do fornecedor já no nfe: '.$transactionReference;
    endif;

require_once ('client-php/lib/init.php');

echo 'codigo do fornecedor já no nfe: '.$transactionReference;
..
..
..
..
..
```

Talvez seja aqui que não estou sabendo pegar a variável.

Comment: Não entendi o que quer dizer com "preciso passar um parâmetro para esta nova url,". O que tem no `$transactionReference`?

Comment: $transactionReference é o código de referência de um ID da minha tabela que deverá ser usada lá nesta nova URL, para retornar o valor que desejo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como passo parâmetros pelo curl?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123866/como-passo-par%c3%a2metros-pelo-curl)

Comment: @DanielOmine é parecida com esta. Mas quero passar um parâmetro, de preferencia como sessão.

Comment: Talvez seja o outro PHP, vou editar a pergunta mostrando o outro PHP...

Comment: bastaria modificar post por get... Mas parece que vc tem uma dúvida secundária que é receber a o parâmetro. Para isso, basta invocar `$_GET['nome_variavel']` ou `$_POST['nome_variavel']`. Mas tem também outra questão que é passar por sessão. Se ambas as páginas são do mesmo domínio, pode simplesmente setar a sessão na primeira página sem necessidade de curl, request, etc.. Está confuso e sem foco o que pede. Se não é duplicada é "não clara o suficiente"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta do [@Daniel Omine](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123883/15089) diz sobre o método POST e  entretanto se for GET poderia simplesmente fazer:

```
$parametro = http_build_query($transactionReference, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://minha_url/envianfe.php?' . $parametro);
```

---

Neste caso supondo que `$transactionReference` seja:

```
$transactionReference = ['ref' => '1', 'conteudo' => 'x'];
```

Ele vai enviar a requisição como:

```
http://minha_url/envianfe.php?ref=1&conteudo=x
```

Na outra página você irá usar:

```
$_GET['ref'];
$_GET['conteudo'];
```

Por exemplo.

---

Não entendi o "de preferencia como sessão", caso se refira a cookie de sessão e caso ambas forem iguais você poderia usar `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` ou `CURLOPT_COOKIE`:

```
$cookies = http_build_query($_COOKIE, '', '; ', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986)  . ';';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Cookie: ' . $cookies
]);
```

Isso iria fazer com que se o usuário acessa a página do A, o curl iria se conectar com a página B usando os cookies que o usuário enviou em A.

---

Caso queria apenas enviar uma informação poderia usar:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $transactionReference);
```

Isso seria exatamente o [explicado nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123883/15089). Na outra página (que vai receber as informações) utilize o `php://input`:

```
$transactionReference = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Obrigado @Inkeliz, era questão de trabalhar ambos os PHP. Muito Obrigado!